# Facebook 'Like' Social Plugin Ampersand Error

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like, urlencode

I'm trying to implement the facebook 'like' button my site, but I'm having a problem when my URL has an "&" in it.  I have tried using `htmlentities`, as well as `urlencode` (which is the closest to working, but not quite).

I have a url like: `example.com/entry.php?id=1&refer=abc`, and I url encode the entire thing for the href for the iframe for the social plugin button, which becomes: `example.com%2Fentry.php%3Fid%3D1%26refer%3Dabc`

Now, when I load the page with this like button, and click "like" it shows me the correct url "`example.com/entry.php?id=1&refer=abc`" but then it says Error next to it, click the error message and I get this error:

The page at `example/entry.php?id=1&amp;refer=abc` could not be reached.

So for some reason it is interpreting the & as an &amp, how does this make any sense?

Thoughts?

Comment: I didn't realize that you had to press the checkmark to accept answers, I thought clicking the Up arrow was good enough.  I accepted answers to all of my asked questions now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use the XFBML version and make use of the [Open Graph Meta Tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) so that you set the url in the `og:url` meta tag and leave the href empty!

When all is done, run link over the [URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to clear the Facebook cache.